# AutoComplete TextBoxList value is submitted as fetched from json

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I'm using autocomplete textboxlist with prototype and having couple of questions on this.

I'm fetching the values from a
demodata.js file which is as

```
[{
    "caption": "Name1",
    "value": "Name1"
}, {
    "caption": "Name2",
    "value": "Name2"
}]
```

Now when i'm submitting the value, the data i received at servlet is

```
[{"caption": "Name1", "value": "Name1"}]
```

Q1.
I need only it's value `Name1` not the whole thing, so how can i achieve it's value.

Q2.
Also i want to change the delimiter for selecting the values. Right now after typing the value if a space is given the value is selected in textbox, i want to change it to `,`. When i press `,` only after that the value should be selected in texbox.

Comment: Q1: `myArray[0].caption` and `myArray[0].value`, _myArray_ is the name of JSON Array.

Comment: It didn't work @Omar . I tried the following

var myArray= $('#names').val();
      console.log(myArray[0].caption+ "  " + myArray[1].value);

Where names is the autocomplete textbox. on Console undefined is printed for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Array
var myArray = [{
 "caption": "Name 1",
 "value": "Name 1"
}, {
 "caption": "Name 2",
 "value": "Name 2"
}];

// Read each index/object in Array
$.each(myArray, function (index, value) {
 alert('-index: ' + index + ' -caption: ' + value.caption + ' -value: ' + value.value);
});

// Values of first index/object
var first_caption = myArray[0].caption;
var first_value = myArray[0].value;

alert('First caption and value in myArray: ' + first_caption + ':' + first_value);
```

If *alerts* annoy you, replace *alert* with *console.log*

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/2FFyN/)**